# netplan - trouble converting gateway6 to "to/via" directive

Tags: networking, 22.04, netplan, ipv6

I'm attempting to update my netplan config to use a `routes` directive instead of `gateway6` since `gateway6` is deprecated.

My working configuration file looks like this:

```yaml
# /etc/netplan/51-cloud-init-ipv6.yaml
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp6: no
            match:
              name: eno1
            addresses:
              - "2607:5300:60:2e26::1/128"
            gateway6: "2607:5300:0060:2eff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
            routes:
              - to: "2607:5300:0060:2eff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
                scope: link
```

While researching, I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1410754/1707437) suggesting I update my config to look like this:

```yaml
# /etc/netplan/51-cloud-init-ipv6.yaml
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp6: no
            match:
              name: eno1
            addresses:
              - "2607:5300:60:2e26::1/128"
            routes:
              - to: default
                via: "2607:5300:0060:2eff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
```

However, with this configuration, `ping6` fails with the error `Temporary failure in name resolution`.

I have tried multiple combinations of options for `routes`, including:

```yaml
routes:
  - to: default
    via: "2607:5300:0060:2eff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
    scope: link

routes:
  - to: default
    via: "2607:5300:0060:2eff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
    scope: link

routes:
  - to: "2607:5300:0060:2eff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
    via: "2607:5300:0060:2eff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
```

etc. I am unsure of how to convert the `gateway6` directive to a `routes` directive successfully. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You previously had in your config:

```
        routes:
          - to: "2607:5300:0060:2eff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
            scope: link
```

This is a separate route from the default route.  You should not drop or modify this when moving from `gateway6` to `routes`.

Your final routes stanza should look like:

```
        routes:
          - to: "2607:5300:0060:2eff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
            scope: link
          - to: default
            via: "2607:5300:0060:2eff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
```

Comment: this + `systemctl reboot` fixed my issue, thank you very much!